# MVVM Binding DataGrid to DataTable shows wrong Column Name

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I am new to C# WPF, Anyone have come across the case before? (MVVM)

I bind the ItemSource of a DataGrid to a DataTable. When I use SQL command "Select * from Testing1" (its connecting to a MDB file), all the data are corrected populated in the DataGrid, except the column Name has some issue. "Underscore" was missing strangely in the column name. I tested below case:

- The correct Column Name is "Testing_Field_3", while it display "TestingField_3".
- The correct Column Name is "Testing_**Field_**_4", while it display "Testing_Field_4". (Displaying underscore in this website have some issue. The case should be that 2 underscore converted to 1 underscore)

When debugging, I checked the DataTable/Recordset, and the column name is correct and no issue.

Below is the extracted part of my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="650" Height="300" Margin="5,5,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SqlDataTbl, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

If it was a bug in C#, any alternative for this?

Kindly appreciate help from you guys and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Reason for this behaviour is [ContentPresenter.RecognizesAccessKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.recognizesaccesskey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is by default `true` for `datagrid header contentPresenter`. If this property is true, it uses `AccessText` in text of header.

Workaround for this is to hook to `AutoGeneratingColumn` event of dataGrid and replace all single underscore with double underscores. Sample is shown below -

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

and in event handler -

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
                                    DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
   e.Column.Header = e.Column.Header.ToString().Replace("_", "__");
}
```

---

Also you can achieve that by `overriding ContentTemplate` of `DataGridColumnHeader`. Use `TextBlock` inside it which does not recognizes access key from a text.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
  <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
  </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where should I add the "DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn()"? (in the ViewModel?)  Also how should I define DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs?

Comment: Event should be in code behind file i.e. `xaml.cs` but i would suggest you to go with second approach rather i.e. overriding `ContentTemplate`.